# How can I find common data with 2 different tags in R?

Tags: r

Am very new to R. My data has columns of Customer ID and Category. Customer ID is numeric and Category is text. 
Customer ID can belong to Category A or B or Both. My queries:

1. Customer ID can be of A / B / Both. How can I filter customer IDs which belong to A only and not to other 2 segments?
2. In the Both segment, how can I know Customer has bought first from A or B?

Please help. Data is looking like this

```
data.frame
(date = c("24 aug", "19 Aug", "15 july", "31 aug", "10 Aug", "12 Aug"), 
id = c(1000003007, 1000008006, 1000008006, 1000008006, 1000009009, 1000010004), 
customer = c("A", "B"))
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNU5g.png)

Comment: Add the input data and desired output in your question.

Comment: Added sample data image. Please help

Comment: add the `dput` or `structure` of your input data frame. Also the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, am not getting your ques. I have already pasted sample image of my data. Can you please clarify how exactly you want me to add data here

Comment: Images of data can't be used by other people (_e.g._ in copy/paste). If you have data in, say, a data frame named `df1`, paste the output of `dput(df1)` in your question. If it's too large, include for example the first 10 lines using `dput(head(df1, 10))`.

Comment: visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Read copy your data section in answer.

Comment: i have added input code but cant add output code (since am too new for R). Based on this data, can you plz help me in solving my queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("24 aug", "19 Aug", "15 july", "31 aug", "10 Aug", "12 Aug"), id = c(1000003007, 1000008006, 1000008006, 1000008006, 1000009009, 1000010004), customer = c("A", "B"))
```

You can use `subset` to get results on your both queries.

Query 1:

```
subset(df, customer == "A")

     date      id       customer
1  24   aug 1000003007      A
3  15   july 1000008006     A
5  10   Aug 1000009009      A
```

if you just want customer id:

```
subset(df$id, df$customer == "A")
[1] 1000003007 1000008006 1000009009
```

Query 2:

```
subset(df, customer == "A" | customer == "B")

     date         id       customer
 1   24 aug   1000003007        A
 2   19 Aug   1000008006        B
 3   15 july   1000008006        A
 4   31 aug   1000008006        B
 5   10 Aug   1000009009        A
 6   12 Aug   1000010004        B
```

if you just want customer id:

```
subset(df$id, df$customer == "A" | df$customer == "B")
[1] 1000003007 1000008006 1000008006 1000008006 1000009009 1000010004
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

You can filter your dataframe with conditions. The general code structure in R to select specific `rows` or `columns` of your dataframe is this:

Assume your dataframe object is called `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("24 aug", "19 Aug", "15 july", "31 aug", "10 Aug", "12 Aug"), 
                 customer_id = c(1000003007, 1000008006, 1000008006, 1000008006, 1000009009, 1000010004), 
                 Category = c("A", "B"))

df[rows, columns]
```

You can call rows and columns by their position in the dataframe using numbers.

```
df[1, ]

    date customer_id Category
1 24 aug  1000003007        A
```

will select the first row and all columns.

```
df[, 1]

[1] 24 aug  19 Aug  15 july 31 aug  10 Aug  12 Aug 
Levels: 10 Aug 12 Aug 15 july 19 Aug 24 aug 31 aug
```

will select all rows, but only the first column. You can also select columns by their name:

```
df[, "customer_id"]

[1] 1000003007 1000008006 1000008006 1000008006 1000009009 1000010004
```

will select all rows, but only the column `customer_id`. This can also be done with `df$customer_id`.

To use conditional selection of rows, you insert a condition into the space before the comma:

```
df[df$Category == "A",]

     date customer_id Category
1  24 aug  1000003007        A
3 15 july  1000008006        A
5  10 Aug  1000009009        A
```

will select all columns, but only rows which fulfill the condition `column "Category" is equal to "A"`.

I cannot answer your second question, as your data example does not include rows with `df$Category == "Both"`.